# How can I examine in gdb a variable that has the same name as its type

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

I'm debugging an existing C library with gdb 7.4
I'm trying to examine a variable which, unfortunately, was declared with the same name as its type:

```
extern const enum rtx_class rtx_class[NUM_RTX_CODE];
```

Now I just can't find a way to examine this variable. `p rtx_class` returns *Attempt to use a type name as an expression*, the same with `p &rtx_class` and `p rtx_class[0]`.
However, `info var rtx_class` works and returns const rtx_class rtx_class[145] as expected.

Any idea?

Comment: For me it's fine for enums (gdb 7.4), but for structs this has been there for a long time: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7737

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this workaround. For your binary do something like:

nm your-executable |grep rtx_class

You should get address (let's say it's 0xabcdef, assuming this is global variable.
Then in gdb do something like:

print *(rtx_class*)(0xabcdef+sizeof(rtx_class)*n)

This should print rtx_class[n]. Or at least it does in my simple testcase.

Comment: Unfortunately modern distros enable ASLR so this no longer helps...